# template metaprogramming to disable functionality of a class

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I have a bunch of loosely coupled classes (with no common interface), and in my application, I have processing using these classes.
I'd like to be able to come up with a generic way to disable some of these classes, so that they don't get compiled or consume runtime resource.

```
class A {
void doA(int a, char b);
};
class B {
void processB();
};
...
int main() {
A a;
B b;
a.doA(1, 'c');
b.processB();
}
```

I can define a template with a boolean argument and specialize it for when it's true, do nothing in doA or processB. But then I have to define template for each of these classes.
Any smart idea to design a generic template that can bypass arbitrary function calls on arbitrary class? e.g.

```
typedef Magic<A, false> AT; // class A is dummied out
typedef Magic<B, true> BT; // class B would still have functionality
int main() {
AT a;
BT b;
a.doA(1, 'c'); // this does nothing and will be optimized away by compiler
b.processB(); // this is real
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need the interface of the classes to remain intact, I can't imagine a fully general solution. I can offer this hack. The idea is to modify the classes by wrapping the bodies of their functions in a macro which can conditionally define the code out:

```
#if /* Condition which controls whether class A should be used */
  #define CLASS_A_BODY(...) __VA_ARGS__
#else
  #define CLASS_A_BODY(...)
#endif

class A
{
  void doA(int a, char b)
  { CLASS_A_BODY(   
    do_stuff_with(a);
    and_with(b);
    as_before(a, b);
  ) }
};
```

Of course, you'd have to do something about functions which return a value (but that is true for any solution).

Comment: Sometimes when we have to do macro, we have to do macro.